# How to force HoloEveryWhere color/assets with Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using `HoloEveryWhere` library with project having min target `android:minSdkVersion="8"`. I converted `Holo` assets with custom color and I want to get those used with every platform version. However tested with `Android 4.4 KitKat` device and regular `Button` and `EditText` are not behaving the same than with older device. Also `ActionBar` behaves native way and not using the wanted `Drawable` I created for background.

With `2.3.x` device everything seems to work just fine.

I see `values-v11` and `values-v14` in `HoloEveryWhere` values folder, do I need to modify these somehow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `values-v11` folder from `HoloEveryWhere` values solved most of the issues. Also remember to set `KitKat Style` to *NO* if you are using `Android Holo Colors` to generate the assets.